# Htaccess redirecting wrong page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

here is my htaccess code

```
# Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ view-product.php?catSeoUrl=$1&subCatSeoUrl=$1&productSeoUrl=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ products.php?catSeoUrl=$1&subCatSeoUrl=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ products.php?catSeoUrl=$1 [QSA,L]
```

the second & third rules are working fine. Please have a look here

http://domain.tdl/consumer-electronics/mobiles.php

http://domain.tdl/consumer-electronics.php

but the First Rule for view Product also redirecting to products.php, have a look.

http://domain.tdl/consumer-electronics/mobiles/product-6.php

its strange, can you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: As soon as the third rule is applied then automatically the third rule gets applied too, since its pattern matches the target of the first rule. With the apache http server from version 2.4 onwards you can use the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag to prevent that. For older apache versions you need to add rewrite conditions.

Comment: @arkascha thx its works now, i mean the END flag. and may i know the details about L and END flag?

Comment: The `L` flag terminates _this iteration_ of the rewrite process, so a new iteration is started until the last iteration does not result in a rewriting any more whilst the `END` flag _finally_ terminates the rewrite engine for that request, not that iteration. That is documented, btw: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the third rule is applied then automatically the third rule gets applied too, since its pattern matches the target of the first rule.

With the apache http server from version 2.4 onwards you can use the END flag instead of the L flag to prevent that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ view-product.php?catSeoUrl=$1&subCatSeoUrl=$1&productSeoUrl=$3 [END]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ products.php?catSeoUrl=$1&subCatSeoUrl=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ products.php?catSeoUrl=$1 [END]
```

For older apache versions you need to add rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ view-product.php?catSeoUrl=$1&subCatSeoUrl=$1&productSeoUrl=$3 [END]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ products.php?catSeoUrl=$1&subCatSeoUrl=$1 [END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^\]+)\.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.php$ products.php?catSeoUrl=$1 [END]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).